# xcode retrieving russian chars out of SQLite DB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, utf-8, sqlite

I have successfully stored Russian characters in my sqlite database. When I query them I see them as Russian chars. They were imported using a UTF-8 encoded file. However, when I retrieve using xcode I get strange char's ie `@"_______"`

Here is the code:

```
NSString *russChars = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,2)];
```

Any ideas would help. I tried a bunch of different variations based on what I can find on here. Nothing works.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I retrieve using Xcode"? You don't use Xcode to read data from the database. Please clarify how you are seeing strange characters.

Comment: Sorry, xcode was the wrong word. When I retrieve data from the sqlite database from within my app using objective-c I get the strange characters.

Comment: Where do you see the strange characters? Are you viewing the variable value in the debugger? Are you using `NSLog` to log the value? Or are the strange values shown a `UILabel` or some other UI component?

Comment: Never mind, this did work. I still had the data encoded to UTF-16 in the database. Once I changed it to UTF-8 it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help maddy.